# Visual Studio 2013 - Windows 7 create app package

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows 7 32x. It seems I'm not able to create an app package in Visual Studio 2013 Professional, the "Store" option doesn't appear. I've read somewhere that we couldn't package on Win7, is there any way around? I'd like to upload my app to Windows Store, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that. On Windows Store development center web site it's stated quite explicitly:

> To create an app, you must use Visual Studio 2013 on a computer running Windows 8.1.
>   You can't create an app by using Windows 7. In addition, developer licenses aren't available for Windows Server 2012, so you can't develop a Windows Store app on that operating system.

More on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx

Check the section "Important"

Comment: Thx mate appreciated it, i guess that'll have to upgrade my system. Cheers, thumbs up.